# How to recalculate Taxes on SO Order Screen

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to recalculate SO Order Screen Taxes?
I Customize UnitPrice and ExtPrice value, but the VAT Taxable Total gets the original UnitPrice and ExtPrice.

Help me please, right now I'm using
`cache.RaiseFieldUpdated<SOOrder.orderDate>(this.Base.Document.Current, this.Base.Document.Current.OrderDate);` because when I change the document date it auto recalculates.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the code for updating Unit Price and Ext Price?

Comment: Hello, I have this code, I will edit the post

Comment: your code is missing the update of the SOLine

Comment: oh. I will try, but it is under RowUpdated Event

Comment: you can't update SOLine price under RowUpdated event and expect correct behavior from Framework. You should update price under FieldUpdated event or separate Action.

Comment: I'm applying it to when the qty changes, because it returns original price, I have implemented my own pricing, which will replace the pricing. the scenario is  that if im on qty and unit price original price displays, when I get past ext.price it seems that it updates after I leave the control, it will correct the price